# Measurement protocol transactions from Google Analytics to Google AdWords

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am correctly sending enhanced e-commerce transactions to Google Analytics via the measurement protocol. In Google Analytics, these transactions get attributed to the correct source / medium of the session in which these transactions actually happened.

When I link Google Analytics to Google AdWords, and import these transactions from Google Analytics into Google AdWords, something goes wrong with the attribution. Google AdWords only records those transactions of which the source / medium in Google Analytics is set to google / cpc. However, normally Google AdWords records all transactions of clients where google / cpc was somewhere in their customer journey (so not only the transactions in which google / cpc was the channel in which the transaction occured).

I'd like Google AdWords to record my imported transactions as it would normally do if you don't send transactions via the measurement protocol, but via regular ecommerce tracking.

Does someone has a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm wanting to do the same thing.

Comment: Any further news on this?

Comment: I would also like to know if you ever solved this