# Google Measurement Protocol Source & Medium

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I have started using GMP on an eCommerce website as I am concerned about transactions not being tracked correctly due to ad blockers and subsequently the conversion data in Adwords being incorrect.

However, I've started using it and I've found it to be a nightmare to get to work as you'd expect. I found this question still unanswered which is worrying!!

[Measurement protocol transactions from Google Analytics to Google AdWords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108067/measurement-protocol-transactions-from-google-analytics-to-google-adwords)

However, my question is similar. But not the same. I'd like to know if I'm supposed to set the referrer, source & medium only once? For the first request?

i.e. Lets say someone clicks an eCommerce shopping ad (So it has a **glid**). Comes onto the site. And I set the medium to **cpc** and the source to **google**.

Then they start to browse around the site before making a purchase. The referrer will then be registered as the current domain and the source and medium will not be recorded.

Is this correct? As currently it's attributing all conversions to the site itself and not to google even though I am passing in the glid on the first request.

Comment: In theory setting the source / medium on the first hit of a session should work. Perhaps you're sending hits out of sequence? Are you able to share a sequence of Measurement protocol hits calls in order to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. They are not out of sequence as they are tied together by the UID, and it's a website so it's per request.

Comment: please edit your question and post the exact hits you are sending associated with your question / issue and I will contact the team and hopefully get you some answers.