# Google Measurement Protocol Transactions Not Showing?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I am using GMP on an eCommerce website as a trial to see if I can pick up all transactions / page views as we are under the impression that a % are not being recorded due to ad blockers.

However, I have tested some code thoroughly via debug and it returns the correct response. But I have pushed this code to the website yesterday to record the page views and enhanced ecommerce transactions.

I waited until we got the first order, went to analytics, after refreshing the conversions page a few times it showed up (Great). So I just left it running for the rest of the day and we had a number of orders come through.

I've just checked it this morning. But all that shows it the same single conversion! Not other data?? It's the same code, I know 100% it's working correctly as I tested and tested it before pushing up. It recorded the first conversion fine. But nothing since.

What on earth is going on with this API? I've see so many people moaning about it. Does it just not work? Or is there a daily limit on hits or transactions it can record? Very frustrating after days of development to get it working and tested.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are using to insert the hits using the measurement protocol. and the code you are using to Extract the data using the Google analytics API.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score -1):

Your question is slightly unclear.  You speak of using the Google Analytics API yet you say you check and there is no hits.  Where exactly are you checking the Google analytics website? Or your application that is using the Google Analytics API to extract data from Google analytics?

You are not going to be able to extract any data from the Google analytics API until it also appears in the Google Analytics website. I would suggest waiting until the data appears on the Google analytics website before worrying that there something wrong with the Google analytics api.

> [Data processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)
>
> Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. To restore intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions your account sends to < 200,000 per day.
>
> For Analytics 360 accounts, this limit is extended to 2 billion hits per month. Learn more about the Analytics 360 data-processing SLA.

Even if you are using the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) to extract Data from google analytics you are still bound by the same data processing latency that the [Google analytics website](https://analytics.google.com/analytics) has.

If all the following are true

1. If as you said you have sent the hits to the debug endpoint of the measurement protocol HTTP GET (https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect) and it worked
2. You changed your code to send a POST request to the collect endpoint before pushing to prodcution

   POST /collect HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.google-analytics.com

   payload_data
3. If you are seeing hits in the real time report on the google analytics website when you send them then i would sujest that they are working.

Then i would suggest that the issue is merely that you need to wait until the data has been processed.

I can assure you that both the Measurement protocol and the Google analytics API work fine.  I have been using them both for years.

Comment: Sorry to say it's still not working. I am using enhanced eCommerce transactions. I don't see what the point in posting the code up is, when it works in debug fine. And when in production it was showing real time AND recorded the first transaction. After that, no transactions have been recorded. Its been 3 days AND still only have 1 transaction for that day! Personally I don't think it's ready to be used for websites and they need much better docs about when and how to use attributes.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203567/google-measurement-protocol-source-medium

Comment: Oh also. Thanks for commenting. It was NOT me that down voted your comment.

Comment: debug isn't perfect if you post the hit you are sending I can help without that no one can help you more

Comment: I have direct email access to the team so can contact them but not with a verifiable example of an issue.